# how can use auth attribute on simple method? Asp.net Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

How Can use Authorize Attribute On A Simple Method , When I Say A Simple Method , Mean Not be on a Controller Or Page Methods , A Realy Simple Methods

Hi Guys , I Need Check Access Of User , in the Method On Inner Services , How Can Achieve it ?

For Controller Or Page We Can Simply Use The Authorize Attribute , But What To Do For Inner Service Of Our Application ?
like I Have A Home Controller , And On Get Call A Method From My Service in Application Layer , I Want To Check This User Has Enough Authority For This Service Then Perform Action

As I said, We Can Use Athorize Attribute on Controller Or Action Or Page Of Razor , But How About Our Simple Method Or Class , Can We Check There For Authority

Comment: It is much simpler to add an exception handle around the code.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: i'm not sure how can this be helpful

Comment: You are asking two questions 1) How can use auth attribute 2) I want to check user has enough authority to perform action.  I'm answering question #2.  You do not want controller to crash so you must handle errors and return an error in the response.   Using exceptions will avoid having to "check access of user" since you will get an exception if processing fails.

Comment: thank You , Yes For Handling Exception This Going To helpful

Answer (score 0):

From inside a service, you should do authorization like this

```
var isAuthenticated = httpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
```

To access the above httpContext from a custom component you should use
[IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

To Use it you have to add services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); to the configurationServices of your startup file.

Below is an example of using IHttpContextAccessor

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserRepository(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    public void LogCurrentUser()
    {
        var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ,   I Have Such Things In My Mind , But For This Question I Need An Answer For Using Auth Like An Attribute On Methods , The Non Action Methods

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a ressource-based authorization

Assuming you already have your policies in place, you can use the `AuthorizeAsync` method from `IAuthorizationService`

For this example, let's say we are trying to check if a user as Edit Rights to edit a document

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(Guid documentId)
{
    Document = _documentRepository.Find(documentId);

    if (Document == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }

    var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService
            .AuthorizeAsync(User, Document, "EditPolicy");

    if (authorizationResult.Succeeded)
    {
        //Call your service here
    }
    else
    {
        //This user don't have access
    }
}
```

Refer to the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-7.0) for more details

Comment: This Is A Good Answer But The Right Answer  To This Question , As I Said , Can Use AuthAttribute On ...
Yes , You Check it Manually But For My Question That Is Not The Right Answer

Comment: Where do you call those inner services of your application, isn't it through a controller ?

Comment: This is Controller , And If I Want To Check Like This Why Put Myself Into This Much Trouble To Write Auth for My Inner Service , Better Use An Authorize Attribute On Action , Controller Or Page , There is No Need For Check Auth Doc Inside Of The Code  , So All Problem Will Solved , But My Problem is Diffrent , I Want Create Auth For InnerService , On Application Layer Or Service Layer , Not Present Layer